Solana 'Account not found' when sending API request
This may seem like a simple issue but I am unsure how to fix 'Account not found' when I send a request to API to fetch user's Solana balance. Any advice would be very helpful!
Error getting account info: Error: failed to get info about account ####(my Wallet): Error: 403 :  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code": 403, "message":"Access forbidden"}
Here's more info on my current set up, I can connect my wallet, but when sending request to API about my wallet, it fails:
Wallet Connection Setup:

Using @solana/wallet-adapter-react for wallet integration
Currently configured for Mainnet (WalletAdapterNetwork.Mainnet)
Using PhantomWalletAdapter with autoConnect enabled
Connection settings: commitment 'confirmed', preflightCommitment
'processed'

Balance Checking Process:

Using getAccountInfo with 'confirmed' commitment
Implementing retry logic (3 attempts with 1-second delays)
Using getBalance with 'confirmed' commitment after account
verification
Refreshing balance every 2 seconds

Transaction Flow:

Creating transaction with latest blockhash
Using confirmed commitment for transaction operations
Transaction timeout set to 60 seconds
Implementing exponential backoff for status checks (10 retries)

Current Issue:

Wallet connects successfully but getAccountInfo returns null
Error suggests account not found despite wallet being connected
This happens consistently even with retry logic
All operations are configured for Mainnet to match user's wallet
network

Key Environment Details:
Network: Solana Mainnet
RPC Endpoint: Using clusterApiUrl(network) from @solana/web3.js
WebSocket endpoint configured automatically from RPC URL
Using standard Solana Web3.js v1.x library
